# CGI best practices on shared hosting

Tags: linux, apache2, joomla3.2

I have installed joomla in a subdomain on my shared hosting server, but the cgi-bin directory is inside the doc root. I would like to move this folder from 
/home/user/public_html/subdomain/joomla_folder/cgi to 
/home/user/public_html/subdomain_cgi 
- I tried adding an alias directive to the joomla .htaccess file in the doc root of the subdomain:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi /home/user/public_html/subdomain_cgi
```

But this shuts down access to https://www.subdomain.com with a server error in the browser window. 
The comments in joomla's htaccess file show no provision for an alias, only redirects.
My provider says that in a shared hosting environment, a cgi-bin directory inside the doc root is fine, but I'm trying to follow best practices. What to do?

Comment: apache is highly unlikely to have access to your home directory, and granting apache access will grant access to everyone else on your shared server as well. essentially you've done NOTHING to help the situation.

Comment: No worries, as you can see I merely attempted to do something that doesn't make sense. I take from your answer that nothing should be done.